# Python random password generator randomly not working

Tags: python, regex, random

I am using the following code for generating some passwords with symbols, numbers and digits.

Sometimes the code works and sometimes not, what is the problem?

```
import random
import string
import re

template="latex code... placeholder ...other latex code"
latex_passwords=''
for _ in range(30):
    password=''.join(random.choice(string.ascii_lowercase+string.digits+string.ascii_uppercase+string.punctuation) for _ in range(12))
    latex_passwords+=password+'\n'

template=re.sub(r'placeholder',latex_passwords,template)
```

Additional details: if you run the code 10 times, almost half of the times it will fail giving the following error at the line with `re.sub()`

```
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.6.4_2/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/sre_parse.py", line 887, in addgroup
raise s.error("invalid group reference %d" % index, pos)
sre_constants.error: invalid group reference 8 at position 169
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`re.sub` interprets sequences of `\number` in the replacement as references to groups in the pattern [(among other escape sequences)](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.sub). You can use a plain string replacement instead:

```
template = template.replace('placeholder', latex_passwords)
```

Comment: The replacement is a randomly generated string, so what can I do?

Comment: @Nisba: You can… use a plain string replacement instead. Like it says in the answer.

Comment: that is use the module template: import template at top and then do as suggested

Comment: Ok sorry I thought that a plain string was an hardcoded string like `"\\0 this gives no problem"`

Comment: ok I found, I have to use `'string'.unicode(utf8string, 'utf-8')`

Comment: @Nisba A plain string replacement means using the `str.replace` method instead of `re.sub` (*regex replacement*)

Comment: Usually we pass raw string (strings with an `r` prefix) to use as regex patterns in the replacement because their backslashes are not interpreted as escapes by python and we need the backslashes for the re specification.

Comment: @progmatico: “in the replacement”, i.e. `latex_passwords`, which may randomly include the backslash character

Comment: @Ryan I don't know if I understood you, sorry

Comment: @progmatico: The issue here has nothing to do with the raw string, which is the pattern to replace and not the replacement. An example of the usual use of the undesirable behaviour is `re.sub(r'([aeiou])', r'(\1)', input)`, which will parenthesize all vowels in the input because `\1` in the replacement refers to group 1 in the match.

Comment: @Ryan you mean that plain is just defined as per Matias comment and I just added to some confusion?